# Most efficient way of saving a product attribute

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 we used to use the 'saveAttribute' function to avoid using the save() function of the product model.

How can we do this in Magento 2? Which ways are best to use?

Edited:

---

Here is my code:

- $key[] = 'url_path';
- $data[] = 'some-uri';

  ```
  if ($this->productModel->getIdBySku($productData['sku'])) {
      $product = $this->productRepository->get($productData['sku']);

      foreach ($productData as $key => $data) {
          $product->setData($key, $data);
          try {
              $this->productResource->saveAttribute($product, $key);
          } catch (\Exception $e) {
              echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.value_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`value_id`, `catalog_product_entity`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (attribute_id='74' AND entity_id='4' AND store_id=0)
```

Importing product 1003

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Method `saveAttribute` is moved to class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` on M2.

So whenever you want to use it, inject an object of class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` and use it. E.g.

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    private $productResource;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource)
    {
        $this->productResource = $productResource;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        //....
        $this->productResource->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
        //....
    }
```

**Updated:**
Please note that your $attributeCode needs to exist in the $product object.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($productData['sku']);
```

In your code, the url_path doesn't exist in the $product object. Can you use the ProductFactory or the ProductCollectionFactory with method addAttributeToSelect('url_path') to get the $product object and retry?

Comment: Thanks, @Toan. But there is something that I'm not doing correctly. I'm getting this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.value_id'. I load the prodcut from repository » I set the data for that attribute » and then execute the saveAttribute action. And I get that error. If I use a 'save' action, it works fine. Any ideas? (I don't know how to provide more details here :S).

Comment: Please update the code to the description. Then I'll help you test it.

Comment: I've updated the description.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: Hi @Toan, I'm not sure what you mean. What difference does it make to load the product from repository or doing it from a collection? I've tried loading the product from Factory, but I've got the same issue :(